# Computing an orthogonal projection,

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I'm trying to find a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is both orthogonal to the space $W$ spanned by $\{(1,2,0,1), (0,1,1,1)\}$ and happens to be "closest" to the vector $(3,3,3,3)$.

From reading Friedberg Insel and Spence and drawing out a diagram, I know that my vector should be $v=(3,3,3,3) - P_{W}v$, where $P_{W}v$ is the orthogonal projection of $(3,3,3,3)$ onto $W$.

How can I compute $P_{W}v$?  Should I try to find a projection matrix of coefficients and apply it to $(3,3,3,3)$, or is there a more geometric way of computing the vector?

Thanks

Edit:  so I was able to answer this question - at least my answer matches that of another student's.  But I was wondering:  the vector that I computed, which is orthogonal to the space W, why do vector addition laws work in 4-dimensions and higher, even though we can't visualize this?  Should I just accept this as fact?  The vector I wanted - and found - was $(3,3,3,3) - P_w(3,3,3,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $A =\left[ \begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right], x = \left[\begin{matrix}3\\3\\3\\3\\\end{matrix}\right]$.

Then $W = range(A)$. The projection of $x$ onto the range of $A$ is $P_R(A) = A(A^TA)^{\dagger}A x$.
where $(A^TA)^\dagger$ is the pseudoinverse of $A^TA$ (but luckily in your case $A^TA$ is nonsingular so it's just the inverse.)

What you want is the projection onto $W^\perp$, which, as you pointed out, is

$P_{R^\perp}(A)x = (I-P_R(A))x = (I-A(A^TA)^{-1}A )x$.

Comment: Hi @whyyes - I edited my question to ask about vector addition laws in 4 dimensions and higher.  What do you think?  Also, thanks so much for your answer.  I actually did it the usual way that reinforces the usage of Gram Schmidt, getting an orthogonal matrix U and then looking at the action of $UU^t$.

Comment: The method here isn't dependent at all on the dimension of $W$, as long as it's finite dimensional. (Not sure if there's something kooky in infinite dimensions but that's another story for another day.) I think what you're doing is more like doing some sort of SVD to find the orthogonal spaces (which also doesn't depend on dimensions) but I think this way is easier. Not sure exactly what you mean about vector addition in 4 dimensions... it seems to me vectors add the same way in all dimensions but maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: ah, I see.  Yea, I was just doing the baby case - in 3D space.  Say a vector (2,2,2), which originates from the origin, then it's orthogonal projection is some vector that is a second edge of a triangle - with (2,2,2) being the first edge.This second edge spans the space W that we are projecting vectors onto.  And if I'm looking for the vector that is closest to (2,2,2) and also orthogonal to the space W, I'd be looking for the third edge of this triangle, namely [(2,2,2) - P_w(2,2,2)], so that with vector addition / parallelogram law, we see that [(2,2,2) - P_w(2,2,2)] + P_w(2,2,2) = (2,2,2).

Comment: So, I was wondering how to make sense of this vector addition in 4D or higher dimensions, @whyyes ...

Comment: Unless there is a much better or abstract reasoning (instead of thinking about vector addition) that holds for higher dimensions... and why [u - P_w(u)] is the desired vector that is both closest to the vector u, as well as orthogonal to the space W?

Comment: The principles you are describing are easy to visualize in 3 dimensions, but are also true in higher dimensions. 

It's a bit hard to visualize this same thing happening in 4 dimensions, but you can also prove this algebraically: if $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W$, then looking at $Q = I-P$, we have:

$QQ = Q, QP = 0$

which are the properties necessary for $Q$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $W^\perp$. This way is a bit more abstract but as you can see the number of dimensions don't matter.